# How to monitor a micro-service oriented solution?

Tags: monitoring, microservices, software-as-a-service

I run a micro-service oriented system, running under a private network, composed mainly of:

- databases (clusters)
- internal API's
- external/public API's
- workers (services)
- monitoring servers

All are running Debian (7/8) and mainly using nginx and supervisor.

I'm currently monitoring logs using ELK stack. But I do want to have a monitoring/alerting system to include the following:

- internal/public API's (calls)
- databases status (only basic, to know when the cluster does not have issues)
- ram/cpu for the servers

What do you recommend to use? I'm more open to open-source solution, but also can pay for services that are mature (not interested in startup solutions)

Comment: If you can spend mich money: dynatrace

Answer (score 2):

[Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) is a popular tool for monitoring microservices deployed to the cloud in combination with [Grafana](https://grafana.com/). For a better understanding of your inter-service issues, a distributed tracing tool is needed as well.